# Customize Client-Id with Paypal

Tags: angular, paypal

I am implementing PayPal's Smart Payment Buttons in my Angular project. I know that in my index.html file I have the following script:

```
<script
    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_CLIENT_ID">
  </script>
```

I am trying to implementing Cart like system, and so there will be multiple Client-Id's depending on which business is using this. Thus, I realized that I need to dynamically set the `MY_CLIENT_ID` to the Client-Id of the business account that is using the site. But all I can find is hard-coding the client-id in the paypal script in `index.html`. I need some way that when I create the order to set the client id in my Angular component. Something like the following:

```
paypal.Buttons({
      clientId: dataService.business.clientId  // **IMPORTANT** PART I NEED TO DYNAMICALLY SET THE CLIENTID
        // THE REST IS JUST TYPICAL PAYPAL BUTTON STUFF.
      createOrder: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [
            {
              description: this.product.description,
              amount: {
                currency_code: 'USD',
                value: this.product.price,
              }
            }
          ]
        });
      },

      onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
        const order = await actions.order.capture();
        this.paidFor = true;
        console.log(order);
      }
    })
      .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
```

I don't believe that merchant-id is what I'm looking for because I know the business's client-id, I just can't hardcode it in, but I'm not sure. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a `PayPalService` like this and call it from the component.

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PaypalService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT)
    private document: Document
  ) {}

  public initiate(clientId: string): Observable<void> {
    const paypalScriptElement: HTMLScriptElement = this.document.createElement('script');

    paypalScriptElement.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}`;
    paypalScriptElement.id = 'paypal-script';

    this.document.head.appendChild(paypalScriptElement);

    return fromEvent<void>(paypalScriptElement, 'load').pipe(first());
  }

  public remove(): void {
    const paypalScriptElement = this.document.getElementById('paypal-script');

    this.document.head.removeChild(paypalScriptElement);
  }
}
```

In your component, use as follows:

```
this.paypalService.initiate(dataService.business.clientId).subscribe(
  () => paypal.Buttons({
      // THE REST IS JUST TYPICAL PAYPAL BUTTON STUFF.
      createOrder: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [
            {
              description: this.product.description,
              amount: {
                currency_code: 'USD',
                value: this.product.price,
              }
            }
          ]
        });
      },

      onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
        const order = await actions.order.capture();
        this.paidFor = true;
        console.log(order);
      }
    }).render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement)
);
```

Make sure to call `this.paypalService.remove()` in `ngOnDestroy` of your component.

Also, make sure to remove any hard-coded PayPal script tags from `index.html` since it will now be added programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was sure that I needed the Client-Id, but now I'm not sure. I'm using the Account ID in my Sandbox Business account which is a 13 digit string, but it gave me an error. Is this the right Account-Id or do I need the merchant-Id to make the transaction go through that business account.

Comment: I tried setting the client-Id to my client-Id and setting the merchant-id to the Id of my other Sandbox business account, but the money went to the account where client-Id is set, not to the account that merchant-Id is set. What is the point of the merchant-Id?

Comment: I am not sure about that. You might want to consult PayPal's documentation.

Comment: hi @AaronAdrian, in typescript if i'm trying to use `paypal.Buttons` i'm getting `Cannot find name 'paypal'` error, how could i solve it? should i make a variable called paypal?

Comment: @IgorMytyuk That's a great question. Add `declare var paypal;` to the top of whichever file you are using PayPal in.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a server-side, API-based integration with v2/orders.

For the front end, you would use the following (the client-id in the front end can be your own): https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This is the most robust solution, and the one used by all major shopping cart platforms.

---

On the backend, you have two options. You could use your own client-id/secret and specify the receiver using the `payee` object: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/ -- however, since you apparently know the receiver's client-id and secret, it seems you should be able to just use them.

Regardless, the two routes you need to implement to pair with your front-end code are 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Comment: Thanks for your frankness. Can you point me to any resources on building a proper v2/orders API backend, as I think this is what I'm going to have to do. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Here is the guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

For verbose detail see the Orders API Reference linked on the left

Comment: Thanks again for your references. I have one other question. From my viewpoint it looks like the only way I can take payments on behalf of other users is by completing this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/partner-onboarding/ but it appears as if I won't get approved until a couple months. I need to be able to take payments very quickly, within the next week, so do you know any alternatives, or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: The link in your answer actually includes the client ID in the front end code. On line 15 of the JS, you can see the client ID is being passed.